# How do I get the cell value from a table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<td> <input type="button" name="buton" id="x2" value="2" onclick="swap(id)";/> </td>
```

This is the button in a table when it is clicked it's id is passed as parameter to function "swap" as below:

```
  function swap(x)
  { 
   document.write(x);
  }
```

It is successful in getting the id but not the value;when i am trying in this way:

```
  function swap(x)
  { 
   document.write(x.value);
  }
```

The output is shown as undefined.  Can you tell me how to get the cell value using the cell id?

Comment: How do you invoke the function `swap`?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that what you are looking for is document.getElementById(x).value;
Also if you want the button just pass this to the function like this:

```
<button onclick="foo(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess use jQuery for the purpose,it allows to traverse in DOM very easily.

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr><th>Customer Id</th><th>Result</th></tr>
<tr><td>123</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>789</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

If you can, it might be worth using a class attribute on the TD containing the customer ID so you can write:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var customerId = $(this).find(".customerIDCell").html();    
 }
```

Essentially this is the same as the other solutions (possibly because I copypasted), but has the advantage that you won't need to change the structure of your code if you move around the columns, or even put the customer ID into a < span >, provided you keep the class attribute with it.

By the way, I think you could do it in one selector:

```
$('#mytable .customerIDCell').each(function()
{
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

If that makes things easier

**Code will be more or less more reliable on cross bowser issue**

Comment: He is a noob, jQuery isn't the way to go here. He needs to know javascript first.

Comment: I'd say still go for the jQuery +1

Comment: Really? how would he know how it's done in the background? Imagine that he comes to a workplace that doesn't use a js framework...

Comment: but still jQuery is better framework,than just simple javascript,It solves the cross browsers issues also,without re-writing the code again and again for separate browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the id of the element you might want to use  `document.getElementById(x)` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

`z = document.getElementById(id);` first, and then you should be able to use `z.firstChild.textContent`

Comment: Not in IE (6 and 7, at least). You'd have to use `innerText` there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the cell using `var cell = document.getElementById(x)`.  Then use `cell.firstChild.nodeValue`.

```
function swap(x)
{ 
    var cell = document.getElementById(x);
    document.write(cell.firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

**EDIT:** Tested this on both FF3.5 and IE8 and it works.

Comment: i think the correct way is cell.firstChild.textContent, atleast in firefox

Comment: In all this approach,you are required to keep writing the same code again and again for separate Browsers...So go for jQuery